# Running a SQL Server Agent Job via ASP.NET, Can I know whether the action would be successful or not

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I sometime run a SQL Agent Job through a Web Page of ASP.NET.

The following is the code for the web page.

```html
Try
            Dim jobConnection As SqlConnection
            Dim jobCommand As SqlCommand
            Dim jobReturnValue As SqlParameter
            Dim jobParameter As SqlParameter
            Dim jobResult As Integer

            jobConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings("MSDB_Con").ConnectionString)
            jobCommand = New SqlCommand("sp_start_job", jobConnection)
            jobCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            jobReturnValue = New SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int)
            jobReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
            jobCommand.Parameters.Add(jobReturnValue)

            jobParameter = New SqlParameter("@job_name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            jobParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            jobCommand.Parameters.Add(jobParameter)
            jobParameter.Value = "DataExportJob"        '<<This is a SQLServer Job>>

            jobConnection.Open()
            jobCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            jobResult = DirectCast(jobCommand.Parameters("@RETURN_VALUE").Value, Integer)   '<<Even though this Job fail, 0 is returned to this value>>
            jobConnection.Close()

            Select Case jobResult
                Case 0
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("SQL Server Agent job, started successfully.")
                Case Else
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("SQL Server Agent job, failed to start.")
            End Select
        Catch
            AlertMessage = "The job Failed!!"
            startupScript = "<script language='JavaScript'> alert('" & AlertMessage & "') <" + "/script>"
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "startup", startupScript)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
```

The problem I'm facing is that even though the result of their action is failed, I couldn't realize the situation.

I'm always getting a good result. 
The value returned by the agent seems to be only about starting. 
How Can I know whether the job action is successful or not?

Comment: That code calls `sp_start_job`. To find a job result use `sp_help_job`

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply! It should work it, I'll try this.